# Android NDK - Fatal signal 11

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, crash, aes

In the app I'm developing on Android (4.2.2), I keep getting a Fatal Signal 11 error. And i dont know why, its just simple method calling from NDK. Im pretty new for this, so if you see something what i cant, ill be grateful.

Story behind: I need implement NDK AES (for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations), because that in Android is terrible slow.

Thanks

Here is my java code:

```
package sk.anext.ecukrovka.ws;

public class AESCrypt {

    private static final String TAG = "AESCrypt";

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("aes256");
    }

    public class aes256_context {
        public byte[] key = new byte[32];
        public byte[] enckey = new byte[32];
        public byte[] deckey = new byte[32];
    }

    public native void aes256test(aes256_context ctx);

    public AESCrypt(AESKey key) throws GeneralSecurityException {

        Log.d(TAG, "This is just simple test of NDK");

        aes256_context ctx = new aes256_context();
        aes256test(ctx); //Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

        Log.d(TAG, "Never reached code..");
    }
}
```

Here is C codes..

Application.mk:

```
# The ARMv7 is significanly faster due to the use of the hardware FPU
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := aes256
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := aes256.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

aes256.h:

```
// #INCLUDE
#include <jni.h>

#ifndef uint8_t
#define uint8_t  unsigned char
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif

    typedef struct {
        uint8_t key[32]; 
        uint8_t enckey[32]; 
        uint8_t deckey[32];
    } aes256_context; 

    void Java_sk_anext_ecukrovka_ws_AESCrypt_aes256test(JNIEnv *, jobject, aes256_context *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

aes256.c:

```
#include "aes256.h"

void Java_sk_anext_ecukrovka_ws_AESCrypt_aes256test(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, aes256_context * ctx)
{
    ctx->key[0] = 0; //simple action with java object
} /* aes256_test */
```

Log:

```
06-19 09:54:44.667: D/jdwp(28150): processIncoming
06-19 09:54:44.667: D/jdwp(28150): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xF, len=0x27, id=0x4B7, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x1C
06-19 09:54:44.670: D/jdwp(28150): processIncoming
06-19 09:54:44.670: D/jdwp(28150): handlePacket : cmd=0x3, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x4B8, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
06-19 09:54:44.672: A/libc(28150): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x45e0001d (code=2), thread 28150 (ample.ecukrovka)
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): $===AEE===AEE===AEE===$
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): p 0 poll events 1 revents 0
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): not know revents:0
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): p 1 poll events 1 revents 0
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): not know revents:0
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): p 2 poll events 1 revents 1
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): aed_main_fork_worker: generator 0x2fb168, worker 0xbea399e8, recv_fd 15
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): p 3 poll events 1 revents 0
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): not know revents:0
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): p 4 poll events 1 revents 0
06-19 09:54:44.674: D/AEE/AED(119): not know revents:0
06-19 09:54:44.675: I/DEBUG(28366): handle_request(15)
06-19 09:54:44.675: I/DEBUG(28366): check process 28150 name:ample.ecukrovka
06-19 09:54:44.675: I/DEBUG(28366): BOOM: pid=28150 uid=10122 gid=10122 tid=28150
06-19 09:54:44.676: I/DEBUG(28366): [OnPurpose Redunant in preset_info] pid: 28150, tid: 28150, name: ample.ecukrovka  >>> com.example.ecukrovka <<<
06-19 09:54:44.781: I/DEBUG(28366): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-19 09:54:44.781: I/DEBUG(28366): Build fingerprint: 'TCT/California/California:4.2.2/JDQ39/vBD7-0:user/release-keys'
06-19 09:54:44.781: I/DEBUG(28366): pid: 28150, tid: 28150, name: ample.ecukrovka  >>> com.example.ecukrovka <<<
06-19 09:54:44.781: I/DEBUG(28366): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 45e0001d
06-19 09:54:45.060: I/DEBUG(28366):     r0 41848700  r1 c7c00019  r2 45e0001d  r3 00000000
06-19 09:54:45.060: I/DEBUG(28366):     r4 4c657108  r5 41849000  r6 00000000  r7 411cad00
06-19 09:54:45.060: I/DEBUG(28366):     r8 bebbe560  r9 411cacf8  sl 41849010  fp bebbe574
06-19 09:54:45.060: I/DEBUG(28366):     ip 5276e537  sp bebbe560  lr 408567d4  pc 5276e538  cpsr 60000030
06-19 09:54:45.062: I/DEBUG(28366): backtrace:
06-19 09:54:45.062: I/DEBUG(28366):     #00  pc 00001538  /data/app-lib/com.example.ecukrovka-2/libaes256.so (Java_sk_anext_ecukrovka_ws_AESCrypt_aes256test+1)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):     #01  pc 0001e7d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):     #02  pc 0004e2dd  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+500)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):     #03  pc 000506a5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+200)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):     #04  pc 00027be4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):     #05  pc 000206f0  [stack]
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366): stack:
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe520  00000001  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe524  00000000  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe528  53de3048  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe52c  53de2e88  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe530  53de3040  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe534  4007f10c  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+608)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe538  41b1089c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe53c  4009250c  /system/lib/libc.so (sprintf+104)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe540  bebbe5b8  [stack]
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe544  00000000  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe548  41c6c368  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe54c  41849000  [heap]
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe550  41849000  [heap]
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe554  418490a8  [heap]
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe558  df0027ad  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe55c  00000000  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):     #00  bebbe560  411cacf4  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          ........  ........
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):     #01  bebbe560  411cacf4  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe564  00000000  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe568  41b21670  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe56c  00000001  
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe570  41b1089c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe574  408862e1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+504)
06-19 09:54:45.063: I/DEBUG(28366):     #02  bebbe578  411cacf4  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe57c  52181e31  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.ecukrovka-2.apk@classes.dex
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe580  5276e537  /data/app-lib/com.example.ecukrovka-2/libaes256.so (Java_sk_anext_ecukrovka_ws_AESCrypt_aes256test)
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe584  41849010  [heap]
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe588  00000101  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe58c  00000000  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe590  40888877  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe594  400d1204  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe598  53de3048  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe59c  53de2e88  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe5a0  00000000  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe5a4  53de2ec0  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe5a8  400d1204  
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe5ac  5276e537  /data/app-lib/com.example.ecukrovka-2/libaes256.so (Java_sk_anext_ecukrovka_ws_AESCrypt_aes256test)
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe5b0  41b1089c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          bebbe5b4  40072ecc  /system/lib/libc.so (free+20)
06-19 09:54:45.064: I/DEBUG(28366):          ........  ........
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near r0:
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     418486e0 41861fa0 400d0c50 532e736f 65747379  ...AP..@os.Syste
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     418486f0 6f6c436d 00006b63 00000020 00000023  mClock.. ...#...
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     41848700 408e7e84 408e82f8 00000001 41849000  .~.@...@.......A
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     41848710 00000000 51837e08 00000000 0000026b  .....~.Q....k...
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     41848720 7379732f 2f6d6574 6d617266 726f7765  /system/framewor
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near r2:
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     45dffffc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     45e0000c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     45e0001c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     45e0002c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     45e0003c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near r4:
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     4c6570e8 520ada94 00000000 00000000 00000000  ...R............
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     4c6570f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000e4  ................
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     4c657108 41c70ec0 00000101 0002000b 00020000  ...A............
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     4c657118 52189e54 5050f9b8 00000de8 52181e31  T..R..PP....1..R
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366):     4c657128 5276e537 00000000 408860e9 00000000  7.vR.....`.@....
06-19 09:54:45.065: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near r5:
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     41848fe0 00000000 00000000 20203a79 00000013  ........y:  ....
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     41848ff0 20202000 00000800 411c2008 00000453  .   ..... .AS...
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     41849000 520adb34 411cacf4 4c6570c8 5224f000  4..R...A.peL..$R
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     41849010 00000023 c4aa6dea bebbe6c0 00000000  #....m..........
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     41849020 bebbe6f4 00000001 00010008 4085b7c0  ...............@
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near r7:
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cace0 411cad10 520adb34 4c657108 00000006  ...A4..R.qeL....
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cacf0 00000000 c7c00019 45e0001d 411cad40  ...........E@..A
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cad00 520aeaac 4c6570c8 520adb34 00000000  ...R.peL4..R....
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cad10 41c6c368 41c6fc48 41a13568 41c6d468  h..AH..Ah5.Ah..A
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cad20 41c25be8 41b21670 41c29fc0 411cad94  .[.Ap..A...A...A
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near r8:
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe540 bebbe5b8 00000000 41c6c368 41849000  ........h..A...A
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe550 41849000 418490a8 df0027ad 00000000  ...A...A.'......
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe560 411cacf4 00000000 41b21670 00000001  ...A....p..A....
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe570 41b1089c 408862e1 411cacf4 52181e31  ...A.b.@...A1..R
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe580 5276e537 41849010 00000101 00000000  7.vR...A........
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near r9:
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cacd8 411cad10 520adb2e 411cad10 520adb34  ...A...R...A4..R
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cace8 4c657108 00000006 00000000 c7c00019  .qeL............
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cacf8 45e0001d 411cad40 520aeaac 4c6570c8  ...E@..A...R.peL
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cad08 520adb34 00000000 41c6c368 41c6fc48  4..R....h..AH..A
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     411cad18 41a13568 41c6d468 41c25be8 41b21670  h5.Ah..A.[.Ap..A
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near sl:
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     41848ff0 20202000 00000800 411c2008 00000453  .   ..... .AS...
06-19 09:54:45.066: I/DEBUG(28366):     41849000 520adb34 411cacf4 4c6570c8 5224f000  4..R...A.peL..$R
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     41849010 00000023 c4aa6dea bebbe6c0 00000000  #....m..........
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     41849020 bebbe6f4 00000001 00010008 4085b7c0  ...............@
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     41849030 00000000 00000000 40890770 411c5300  ........p..@.S.A
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near fp:
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe554 418490a8 df0027ad 00000000 411cacf4  ...A.'.........A
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe564 00000000 41b21670 00000001 41b1089c  ....p..A.......A
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe574 408862e1 411cacf4 52181e31 5276e537  .b.@...A1..R7.vR
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe584 41849010 00000101 00000000 40888877  ...A........w..@
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe594 400d1204 53de3048 53de2e88 00000000  ...@H0.S...S....
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near ip:
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e514 f7ff4628 4628fe37 fddbf7ff f7ff4628  (F..7.(F....(F..
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e524 3e01fd98 4628d1e7 f7ff4621 e8bdfd9e  ...>..(F!F......
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e534 230081fc 47707013 e5903000 e3130101  ...#.ppG.0......
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e544 13833102 03c33102 e0800003 e12fff1e  .1...1......../.
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e554 e92d4ff0 e1a04000 e59f51a8 e24dd014  .O-..@...Q....M.
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366): memory near sp:
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe540 bebbe5b8 00000000 41c6c368 41849000  ........h..A...A
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe550 41849000 418490a8 df0027ad 00000000  ...A...A.'......
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe560 411cacf4 00000000 41b21670 00000001  ...A....p..A....
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe570 41b1089c 408862e1 411cacf4 52181e31  ...A.b.@...A1..R
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     bebbe580 5276e537 41849010 00000101 00000000  7.vR...A........
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366): code around pc:
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e518 4628fe37 fddbf7ff f7ff4628 3e01fd98  7.(F....(F.....>
06-19 09:54:45.067: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e528 4628d1e7 f7ff4621 e8bdfd9e 230081fc  ..(F!F.........#
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e538 47707013 e5903000 e3130101 13833102  .ppG.0.......1..
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e548 03c33102 e0800003 e12fff1e e92d4ff0  .1......../..O-.
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     5276e558 e1a04000 e59f51a8 e24dd014 e59f31a4  .@...Q....M..1..
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366): code around lr:
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     408567b4 3497c004 3488c004 3afffff9 e2888004  ...4...4...:....
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     408567c4 eafffff9 e899000c e59bc00c e12fff3c  ............<./.
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     408567d4 e3560000 159bc010 e24bd014 188c0003  ..V.......K.....
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     408567e4 e8bd8bc0 e1a0ce22 e59b6008 e2866001  ...."....`...`..
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     408567f4 e3a02000 e4d6c001 e35c0000 0a000007  . ........\.....
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366): memory map around fault addr 45e0001d:
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     41bc9000-41c94000 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     41c94000-4984a000 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 09:54:45.068: I/DEBUG(28366):     4984a000-4c2f5000 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark-stack (deleted)
```

Comment: Somewhere in your logcat will be a C core dump.  Post it.  If you can't find it, make sure to turn off all filters.  Signal 11 means you accessed an illegal memory address BTW.  But without more info we can't tell where.

Comment: Also-  making your own AES implementation is a HORRIBLE idea.  Not only are you likely to have a bug, but there are crypto attacks based on how long it takes to encode data, meaning that the optimizations you put in will likely cause it to be less secure even if you write them perfectly.  If you must do this, use a crypto library written in C and already tested.  Although likely the Android implementation is already doing this.

Comment: Log updated. I dont wanna make my own AES (im not so experienced). Just use some of these http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations.

Comment: So the address you're faulting on looks random, and its at the very beginning of your function.  Most likely ctx isn't initialized.

Comment: Im confused. I did not send him there initialized? I also tried initialize java arrays in loop, without success. Still same problem.

Comment: You're mixing up C++ and Java variables.  If you initialize a aes256_context in Java, that's a java variable.  You can't just access it in C++, you have to pass it as a jobject and use JNI to read fields.  Or it needs to be a C++ object.  The two languages don't just share variables for complex types.

Comment: Solved using JObjects .. thanks